# Struct array's first element become nill after sorting

Tags: c++

I write code to read student name and their CGPA from a text file and save them in an array of type structure and then sort them in ascending order according to the CGPA. After sorting array’s first element is blank, why?

Structure for type student

```
struct student{
      char name[20];
      float cgpa;
};
```

Code to read file

```
while(!inFile.eof()){    
   inFile>>students[i].name >> students[i].cgpa;  
   cout << i << "\t" << students[i].name << "\t\t" << students[i].cgpa << endl;
   i++;  
}
```

Swap function for sorting array content in ascending order according to the CGPA.

```
void swap(student studentsRcrd[]){
 student tempValue;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){      
      for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
         if(studentsRcrd[j].cgpa > studentsRcrd[j+1].cgpa){
                tempValue = studentsRcrd[j];
                studentsRcrd[j] = studentsRcrd[j+1] ;
                studentsRcrd[j+1] = tempValue;
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Final output on command prompt

```
No      Name            CGPA
0       ▄               0
1       Maria           2.4
2       Humza           2.6
3       Saira           2.6
4       Anila           3
5       Junaid          3
6       Usman           3.4
7       Aasim           3.5
8       Talaal          3.8
9       Haris           3.9
10      Ahmer           4
```

Comment: Hint: What happens in your inner for loop when `j == 9`? Answer: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Split this into smaller pieces, so you can figure out if there are problems with reading-in the data, or the sorting.

Comment: @40two with j==9 it shows correct results 
but not with condition j<10

Comment: ok thank @juanchopanza and one more question, why people always mark my question negative ?

Comment: Probably because you have a trivial problem and seem to have made no effort to solve it. This is not a code debugging service.

Comment: @SanaKhan _"Why people *always*..."_ Looks like you joined SO today only. Or may be you have several bunch of StackExchange accounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap function must be looks like this

```
void swap(student studentsRcrd[]){
 student tempValue;
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++){      
      for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
         if(studentsRcrd[j].cgpa > studentsRcrd[j+1].cgpa){  
                tempValue = studentsRcrd[j];
                studentsRcrd[j] = studentsRcrd[j+1] ;
                studentsRcrd[j+1] = tempValue;
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Because when j==10 then studentsRcrd[j+1] will be studentsRcrd[11] and on this position do did not put any thing so its having zero, so while sorting function put this zero on the top because its most smaller value and you are print then in ascending order. 
So change loops condition to the

```
i < 9
```

and

```
j < 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having data for 10 members! That is 0 to 9. But when you use-

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ 
   for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
```

when `j == 9` it will swap the data with next memory location(`j = 10`), This is not in your range!
Try this-

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++){  // Make i<9 and j<9
      for(int j=0; j<9; j++){ // when j == 9, it will swap the data with next memory location
         if(studentsRcrd[j].cgpa > studentsRcrd[j+1].cgpa){
                tempValue = studentsRcrd[j];
                studentsRcrd[j] = studentsRcrd[j+1] ;
                studentsRcrd[j+1] = tempValue;
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Sathish but dont you think i need j<10 because there are 10 elements in array

Comment: @SanaKhan i have explained with the code you have posted!

Comment: @SanaKhan but array index from `0...9`. So `studentsRcrd[j+1]` will try to access `10` index.which cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: ok thank @sathish one more question, why people always mark my question negative ?

Comment: ok thank @Jayesh and one more question, why people always mark my question negative ?

Comment: @SanaKhan Its not like that! if your question is not upto the standard of stackoverflow or if your question seems to be board or if you ask to wrote program with out your effort you will get negative marks! There are lot of facts are there! before asking a question think yourself, is it worth to ask!

Comment: @SanaKhan I don't seems ur question marked as negative.

Comment: @Jayesh some body has marked it negative, my account will be locked.

Comment: @SanaKhan It may happen because of..if you ask simple question(like it's already answered on first page of your book)...or if you not provide enough code/information regarding issue..OR if you provide more then enough code/information which are not necessary..OR if you demand reddy code with out knocking yourself..OR if you  complain again's anyone's useful suggestion..OR...many more. So keep this things in mind before asking question to avoid `-Ve` :)